# Visual studio 2022 find and replace options preservation changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

With Visual Studio 2019, when I changed the options (case sensitivity, whole word or not) of the local "find & replace", these settings were persisted and reused for all the other files.

In Visual Studio 2022, this seems to be the case only for the global "find in files" dialog, no more for the local "find overlay" of a file. Instead, the local "find" settings seem to be persisted on a per file basis, meaning I have to change them for each file in which I have not yet done a local find.
And when I do a search with "unusual" options for me, instead of changing them on the next search done anywhere, I will have to change them on the next search in that particular file. This may happen at such a later time that I will no more pay attention to these settings, not remembering I have used special ones for my previous search in that file.

I find this quite annoying. I have not found an option to revert this to the 2019 behavior. Is there a way to revert it?

What I name the "local find & replace" is this layer in the file editor:

[image: local find][image: local find and replace]

The settings are the buttons and the drop down list at the bottom of the overlay.

Comment: This has been hugely frustrating for me as well, though my problem seems even worse because they don't persist even for the same file (at least, not across sessions). I use regular expressions for a vast majority of my find/replace operations, and I constantly have to remember to toggle that button every time.

Comment: It is not strongly persistent for me neither, even on a per file basis. There is some kind of persistence at play on a per file (or per editor window) basis, but that is not actually permanent. I have not bothered determining what was it really. Anyway the way it persists or not the option is a (small) mess from my viewpoint, since VS2022.